# Textbook or Video Course in probability

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, measure-theory

I am an engineering student and I studied probability textbook by Sheldon Ross and Engineering Statistic by Montgomery. However, I need to know more about the mathematics of probability and statistics. More precisely, I am eager to know about measure theory, what is the relationship/differences between measure theory and probability, probability metrics like Wasserstein metric, etc. I would be thankful if you can recommend any textbook or video course which is better.

Comment: Measure theory/probability primer on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL17567A1A3F5DB5E4). Great lectures on measure theory on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5xeijzKJaIjO5tP5Gzrwhon_VxnWOBKa).

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=measure+theory+wiki%3Ayes.